# Multi-language redirect url to same page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to redirect to same page where is my (select/link) selected or clicked (language).
It redirect me to `redirect(base_url());` my home page even if i change language on other page/views. How can i fix this

This is my LangSwitch controller:

```
class LangSwitch extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    function switchLanguage($language = "") {
        $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "english";
        $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

This is my Language Loader controller:

```
class LanguageLoader
{
    function initialize() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->helper('language');

        $site_lang = $ci->session->userdata('site_lang');
        if ($site_lang) {
            $ci->lang->load('nav_menu',$ci->session->userdata('site_lang'));
        } else {
            $ci->lang->load('nav_menu','english');
        }
    }
}
```

This is my TestLanguage Loader controller:

```
class TestLanguage extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lang->load("nav_menu","english");
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    function index() {
        $data["main_production"] = $this->lang->line("main_production");
        $this->load->view('nav_menu', $data);
    }
}
```

I use this path for my link:

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>langswitch/switchLanguage/english">
```

Comment: When you switch language you ALWAYS redirect to base_url(); That's why you endup in the homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to redirect to last visited url :

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
} else {
    redirect(base_url());
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: And i have this problem. how can i echo `$data["menu_production"]` instead of `$this->lang->line("menu_production");` it work when i echo `($this->lang->line("menu_production");)` but not with $data or other variable

In my controller i call this function
        `function index() {
           $data["menu_production"] = $this->lang->line("menu_production");
           $this->load->view('menu', $data);
        }`

Comment: you mean after adding : `$data["menu_production"] = $this->lang->line("menu_production");` and then calling it in view using `echo $menu_production` it's not working?

Comment: Yes, it not working neither with echo $menu_production

Comment: Is there any error message? What about `echo lang('menu_production')`?

Comment: Are you sure the variable name is `menu_production` not `main_production` ?

Comment: Yes, it is menu_production, i just update the name everywhere instead of `main`.
I don't understand why when i add to `$data["menu_production"] = $this->lang->line("menu_production");` `echo $menu_production` or `$data` (say that i have not defined) maybe i need to call `function index()` somewhere on the view or? I dont know